# How to deal with a force close

Tags: android

I am currently developing a game application for Android. My problem is that it sometimes crashes and displays the "Unfortunately...has stopped" dialog. But running the application again does NOT force close the app when getting to the same point, it will just appear every so often.

What are some potential reasons that this might happen? I've done some research but couldn't really find anything

Comment: maybe you use heap memory too much? try use larger heap

Comment: please add logcat message

Comment: i was developed the app in android version 2.3.3 and the apk size is 30mb. this game is a spot the difference game and it has trivia, i put all the trivia in sqlite.

Comment: that was my another problem, i cant see the logcat message because i was just transferring the apk file to my phone to test it. because my emulator does not carry the size of the game.

Comment: you can find the reason in Logcat

Comment: You can see the log even if you transferred apk file.Check that.The reason might be memory issue

Comment: Definitely, looks like a memory leak... You can fix it by optimizing your code, as an example ensure you are not creating several time a same fragment instead of replacing it.

Comment: Jas how can see the logcat?

Comment: Virthuss do you mean having the same codes repeatedly?

Comment: This is where unit tests shine. However, from the explanation it seems like the images you are using are too large. Either that or there is a memory leak.

Comment: @Angel Whatever you are using, Android Studio or Eclipse with ADT, you must be able to find a LogCat tab. You find it usually at the bottom of your IDE. In both IDEs either when you run or debug your app the LogCat tab usually pops below.

Comment: MarkSkayff I know where to locate the logcat in eclipse i was using, but what i am asking to Jas is how can i see the logcat message about the unfortunately stop of my app when i already transfer the apk file to my phone and run it there, and not in my emulator. because when i was running the emulator when it crashed i can easily detect the error in logcat message but because my app is too large that theemulator cannot carry it, i decided to just copy the apk file in my phone to test it

Comment: @Angel You must run your application through your physical device connected with the Eclipse. If you have your phone connected through USB you can select it as the device through the device manager. And the logcat will output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review your logcat for possible Exceptions.

If you have no Exceptions causing your app to crash -meaning your code is aparently "ok"- there's the chance the application is consuming lots of memory. If your application is making your Garbage Collector to overwork, Android may shut down your application.

You must take care you are not overcreating objects, or leaving a load behind to be cleaned by the Garbage Collector. This means, if you can reuse objects, that's a good idea.

There's an `<application>` element in the Android Manifest. You can set there an attribute named **android:largeHeap="true"**. In this way Android will assign more memory for your application. But do do this as a last resort. Try to first improve the object management in your app. This ain't easy task, so good luck.

Comment: yes i really think i was using so much objects and variables in my codes, they are too long and some of the activity has the same codes. i was not familiar on how to do classes that can handle the same codes, because i was new in programming, literally the code was very very long

Comment: @Angel Yes, repeated code is viewed as a bad practice in programming and something to be avoided. You have to think in modularizing your app. If you see something starts getting repeated, you can think well, how I can pull this off, place it somewhere else where I can reuse it in all those sections -now I'm currently repeating it-

Comment: thanks i will try to minimized all the repeated codes. i just wanna clarify something, why did you say to do the largeheap as last resort? is it not very advisable to use?

Comment: @Angel Basically because it's a good practice to review your object management first. But you can implement largeHead right from the beginning. If it's a game it's ok.